# What is the vibration when I picked up an iPhone 7 Plus that feels like a gyroscope?

Tags: iphone, ios

Recently when I pick up my iPhone 7 Plus (especially when it is charging), there was some kind of vibration that felt like a turning gyroscope which I played when I was a kid. And then after picking up the phone for 10, 20 seconds, the vibration would stop. What was it about? If it was a gyroscope, what was it turning for?

Answer (score 3):

i think it's Taptic Engine. This engine can turned off.

If you like to disable go to Settings -> Sounds & Haptics - > System Haptics -> turn off.

Taptic Engine is different from 3D Touch. So disabling haptics won’t turn off 3D touch.

Comment: does the Taptic Engine turn and want to maintain some kind of inertia?

Comment: isn't the Taptic Engine about 3D Touch, and not related to something rotating and vibrating?